# Is Task.Run faster than ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkerItem?

Tags: c#, threadpool, .net-4.5, async-await, xamarin

I switched my Xamarin.Android app over to use async await in place of the prior ThreadPool.QueueUserWorker item usage and it appears, while having no metrics, that it's faster!  There could obviously be other optimizations in this new build of Xamarin Android but I'm curious from a C# standpoint (.NET 4.5) if in fact Task.Run would be faster as it's starting the task on demand and not queuing the thread pool?

Anyone have information that async await can and will be faster than ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkerItem implementations?

Comment: `async` doesn't itself use other threads. Is it possible that you are just seeing accidental better usage of the thread pool? So I mean less contention of threads, less starvation of the pool, etc.

Comment: No, Task.Run uses the thread pool too, unless you schedule it on a particular scheduler. Are you actually *calling* Task.Run yourself though? It would help if we could see some code...

Comment: Yes, I'm wrapping my code with:  Return Task.Run( ()=> { code here });

Comment: Question (and possible answers) would be more useful to others if it showed where async/await are used w.r.t. the Task.Run call.  Is this  `await Task.Run(() => { ... DoStuff(); ... }`, or `Task.Run(() => { ... await DoStuff(); ...  }`?  And `faster` could mean `UI is less laggy` (but the actual work might still take as long or longer), or it could mean `the work completes faster`.  Pondering what would be a useful question and answer on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

No. It would be slower.

`QUWI` is a very low-level call. `Task.Run` must at the very least create a `Task` and then queue it (which would be similar to `QUWI`).

I suspect your test code is falling into one of the [many](http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one) [pitfalls](https://tech.pro/tutorial/1295/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-two) of micro-benchmarking.

Comment: Actually, since it seems he changed his entire program from one async system to another it seems more likely to me that he's changed so much he just can't tell where the actual performance improvements came from.  If he used a better algorithm using the new system, is avoiding the creation/use of some threads or thread pool time, etc. then that could be where the improvement is coming from

Comment: @Servy Got to agree with you here, my rough guess is that the changes have altered how the thread pool is being utilised such that less threads overall are being used, or at different times and as such thread starvation isn't occurring (for example).

Comment: I think there are some corner cases where `Task.Run()` will be faster (thanks to thread-local queues and/or task inlining), but in general, you're right.